# Codeigniter: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean in

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm developing a website using Codeigniter framework. I wanna ask, I just got this message suddenly when I reload the page:

> Call to a member function result_array() on boolean in

And even if I change into `$this->db->result()`, I still got the message:

> Call to a member function result() on boolean in

and so when I call other sql query result function. Please help me, if anyone know the tricks and hints to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, i.e. a code that the readers can execute.

Comment: Probably connect function fails and returns FALSE which gets assigned to $this->db. You must improve error handling.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to answer without seeing the code. But hope this helps.

Try like this.

```
$query = $this->db->get('tablename');
$query->result();
```

or

```
$this->db->get('tablename')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I php codeIgniter:-

**result_array:-**

This function returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
```

***Message: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean***

This error is the category of
**Codeigniter Fatal error:**

***Fatal error*** : if the table is empty,2 Answers.

1-You should be checking to see if the query worked/has any rows before trying to get its results.

2-You should be checking to see if the query worked/has any rows before trying to get its results. If the table is empty, then the query won't do anything.

- I have also face this issue when passing non-existing column name in my `get_where() query()`.

**In Code:-**

```
<?php $teachers = $this->db->get_where('teachers', 
                                     array('is_deleted'=>0))->result_array();
                         foreach ($teachers as $row){
                          $count=$count+1;}
                          echo $count;
                         ?>
```

**Note**:-
Like in  code example make sure that the column name ***is_deleted*** which use provided to fetch data through `get_where()` also exit in table of your **db**.

[image: Db Picture]